# How to stop sql query streaming in node

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, stream, node-mssql

I am using [node-mssql](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) along with node.js v10.16.0. I use it to stream big amounts of data and use websockets to send that data to the client, and it works fine. In the front-end I have vue.js.

My problem is that when streaming starts it does not stop. Even if the user changes tabs in the front-end app, big amount of data keeps on streaming, even if I close the websocket connection. But there is no point in keep streaming data, since the user is on another tab and cannot see the data.

I can send some data from client to server, before user changes tabs, using websockets so I can alert the same node function that started the stream, to stop it. But I cannot make the stream stop somehow.

Here is my code:

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();

const testStream = (ws , id) => {       
    let request;
    //if id came as 'close', then user changed tab, so stop streaming
    if (id == 'close') {
       request.pause();
       sql.close();
       return;
    }

    poolConnect.then((pool) => {   
      request = new sql.Request(pool);
      request.stream = true;   
      request
      .input('id_param', sql.Int, parseInt(id))
      .query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id_param ')  

      let rowsToProcess = [];
      let data = [];  

      request.on('row', row => {   
        rowsToProcess.push(row); 
        if (rowsToProcess.length >= 20) {  
          request.pause();
          processRows(false);
        } 
      });

      request.on('done', () => {      
        processRows(true); 
        sql.close(); 
      });

      const processRows = () => { 
          rowsToProcess.forEach((item)=>{ 
                data.push(item.name);   
                data.push(item.surname);   
                data.push(item.age);   
            });    
          ws.send(JSON.stringify({ success:true, message: data }));
          rowsToProcess = [];
          data = []; 
         setTimeout(
          ()=>{request.resume();}
          , 100
         );//make it asynch with timeout
      }//processRows 

    }) //poolConnect.then
```

The data telling to close the stream actually reach the function, and go to that part:

```
    if (id == 'close') {
       request.pause();
       sql.close();
       return;
    }
```

But, the problem is that is `request is undefined`, since it is already defined and running I guess I can comment it out and just use `sql.close();` but the stream keeps going.

What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**IMO,** `request is undefined` error is logical because nothing is assigned to `request` at that point. You can declare the `request` variable outside the `testStream` function. But, there is still a problem. If `testStream` gets executed twice (or more) then `request` will be modified on second call. So, you should maintain an array/map or something to identify each `request` and `pause` them accordingly. Also, if `request` is a stream the you should be able to call `.destroy()` to destroy the stream.

Comment: Fair, logical points.So, there is no other way to access that stream? Also, what do you mean by `If testStream gets executed twice (or more) then request will be modified on second call` ? I think that every time `testStream` is called, it will change the request accordingly.

Comment: I meant, if you define `request` variable outside of `testStream` function then whenever you call  `testStream` function the value of `request` will get changed. Because, you are doing this `request = new sql.Request(pool);` in the function. Right? That is why I have suggested to use an array/map or something similar to keep track of each request stream.

Comment: i made some progress. I put the `let requestGlobal ;` as a global var outside the `testStream ` function, the code `if (id == 'close') { request.destroy();`  gets executed, but I get ` requestGlobal.destroy is not a function` Any thoughts? Thanks again

Comment: I can do `requestGlobal.cancel();` but it throws an error and stops the whole node. How can I handle that error?

Comment: Now I get what you mean. I need an array to save the request for each client. But I have to give each request a unique identifier somehow. Also, I dont think this is viable/fast if a lot of clients connect. Any thoughts appreciated

Comment: @codebot Yes, you are right. You have to have some kind of unique identifier. Why do you think it won't be viable/fast? If you are done processing one client remove it from the array. Thus, it won't leak memory. I do not see any problem here.

Comment: I dont know, I guess if there are 1000+ clients, browsing the array/map will get slower. Anyway i am going to try 2 things. (1) Create an array for clients , as we talk (2) not having the request as a global var, and sending a `close` flag that starts a new small query that brings back no data. This is not stoping the stream per se, but it gets the job done, since user is in another tab,.